# How to fix ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 CRC mismatch?

Tags: nvidia, glibc, segmentation-fault

Not sure how I came to getting this problem but for some reason `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is reporting a CRC mismatch and it's effecting a program that I cannot open which results in a segfault.

the application that requires this is `nvclock_gtk`

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/nvclock_gtk 
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.19.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I tried doing a reinstall of libc6 and libc6-dev but this didn't work. What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT:**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc62e3000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3e0a27000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3e0775000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3e0527000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3e02d6000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3dffce000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fe3dfc98000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fe3dfa86000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe3df882000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe3df663000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe3df29e000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3df09a000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3dee8c000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fe3dec86000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3dea64000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007fe3de758000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3de537000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3de1c4000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fe3ddfae000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fe3ddd72000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe3dda6c000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fe3dd861000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007fe3dd65e000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fe3dd44e000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007fe3dd243000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007fe3dd039000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fe3dce36000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fe3dcc32000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007fe3dca29000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fe3dc820000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fe3dc5e2000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fe3dc3c3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe3e10ab000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fe3dc11f000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fe3dbe76000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fe3dbc4f000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fe3dba4c000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fe3db843000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe3db629000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe3db421000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fe3db1fd000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fe3dafe2000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007fe3dad8d000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fe3dab62000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007fe3da95b000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fe3da756000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fe3da550000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007fe3da333000)
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28834807/4937930 Could you show output of `ldd /usr/bin/nvclock_gtk`?

Comment: @yaegashi updated my main post there.

Comment: Did you also upgrade libc6-dbg as in the post I mentioned?  Note that it might fix debugging libs mismatch,  not fix your segfault problem...

Comment: @yaegashi I reinstalled everything related with `libc6` and it didn't fix it.

Comment: Still no answer responses to this?

Comment: Dead-end question with zero answers.

Comment: `"does not match "/lib64/libc.so.6" (CRC mismatch).` In my case, the debug info package has different version. `glibc-debuginfo-common-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64`, `glibc-debuginfo-2.28-39.fc29.x86_64`
, `glibc-2.28-33.fc29.x86_64`, `glibc-common-2.28-33.fc29.x86_64`.  So, I just upgrade `glibc` to 39. and the warnings disapear.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; I solved it by uninstalling the package libc6-amd64:i386:

```
sudo apt-get remove libc6-amd64:i386
```